# Taking a file and splitting it into 2 groups

Tags: c#, list, file-io

So below I have a piece of code that will take a data file and split into two groups, a and b.

```
string path = @"c:\users\povermyer\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DanProject\PNRS\PNRS.log";

string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);
var count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
List<string> groupA = lines.Take(7678).ToList();
List<string> groupB = lines.Skip(7678).Take(5292).ToList();
```

For clarification, the first group takes the first 7678 lines of the code and places it into the group while the second group skips the first 7678 lines and places the rest of lines, 5292 lines, in the group. The only problem with this, is that if I were to use future files, it might not contain 7678 for the fist and 5292. I know that the beginning of the first group starts with A and ends with A, and the second group starts with B and ends with B. So my question is, how do I get that code above to place the file into 2 groups depending on how they start and end?

Also, the lines that start and end are not alone. For example, the beginning of a is

```
***********BEGIN PROCESSING A PNRS*********** and the end is ************END PROCESSING A PNRS************`
```

and its the same with group B. Please help!

Comment: Have you checked in MSDN - maybe there are other TakeXXX/SkipXXX functions that could be helpful? Not exactly sure what you have problem with...

Comment: So what do you want to capture from the sample line you provided?  Just what's between A ... A?

Comment: On the beginning line for example, I want to capture the A. I want to group them into lists, the start of the group being that A ad the end of the group ending with that A. Does that make sense?

Comment: So the results of the sample line would be "A PNRS*********** and the end is ************END PROCESSING A" and if there was a B group is would be "B PNRS*********** and the end is ************END PROCESSING B"?

Comment: Yes I believe that would work.

Comment: Or are you wanting "and the end is", and there would be one for Group A and one for Group B if the data was like that?

Comment: No. In this text file there are over 12,000 lines. Each group starts with what is above and ends with what is above. I want the information in those, but In order to do what I want I need a start to my group somewhere. So ideally if it could just look and if it starts with what you suggested and end with what you suggested, it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you ever have to break out more groups, you may want to consider storing your groups in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where the key is the group name and the value is the List containing only the group data.

### UPDATE

If I'm understanding the scenario, say you have data that looks like:

```
"***********BEGIN PROCESSING A PNRS*********** the beginning is 1 ************END PROCESSING A PNRS************",
"***********BEGIN PROCESSING A PNRS*********** the beginning is 2 ************END PROCESSING A PNRS************",
"***********BEGIN PROCESSING B PNRS*********** and the end is 1 ************END PROCESSING B PNRS************",
"***********BEGIN PROCESSING B PNRS*********** and the end is 2 ************END PROCESSING B PNRS************",
"***********BEGIN PROCESSING AB PNRS*********** good morning to you 1 ************END PROCESSING AB PNRS************",
"***********BEGIN PROCESSING AB PNRS*********** good morning to you 2 ************END PROCESSING AB PNRS************"
```

You want to have it grouped like:

```
A: 
[0] the beginning is 1
[1] the beginning is 2
B:
[0] and the end is 1
[1] and the end is 2
AB:
[0] good morning to you 1
[1] good morning to you 2
```

This would probably work best with `Regular Expressions` and I would still suggest storing everything in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

### NEW CODE

```
/// <summary>
/// Separates the List of string data into groups of data
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">Array of string data</param>
/// <param name="groupNames">Array of group names</param>
/// <returns>Dictionary of List of string data broken into groups</returns>
private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> SeparateGroups(string[] data, params string[] groupNames)
{
    return groupNames.ToDictionary(
        groupName => groupName,
        groupName => data.Select(d => {
            Match m = Regex.Match(d, String.Format("^\\*{{11,}}BEGIN PROCESSING {0} PNRS\\*{{11,}}\\s(.*)\\s\\*{{11,}}END PROCESSING {0} PNRS\\*{{11,}}$", groupName));
            return m.Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : String.Empty;
        }).Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList()
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] groupNames = new[] { "A", "B" , "AB" };
string[] lines = new[] {
    "***********BEGIN PROCESSING A PNRS*********** the beginning is 1 ************END PROCESSING A PNRS************",
    "***********BEGIN PROCESSING A PNRS*********** the beginning is 2 ************END PROCESSING A PNRS************",
    "***********BEGIN PROCESSING B PNRS*********** and the end is 1 ************END PROCESSING B PNRS************",
    "***********BEGIN PROCESSING B PNRS*********** and the end is 2 ************END PROCESSING B PNRS************",
    "***********BEGIN PROCESSING AB PNRS*********** good morning to you 1 ************END PROCESSING AB PNRS************",
    "***********BEGIN PROCESSING AB PNRS*********** good morning to you 2 ************END PROCESSING AB PNRS************"
};

int count = lines.Length;
Dictionary<string, List<string>> groups = SeparateGroups(lines, groupNames);

foreach (string key in groups.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(key + ":");
    foreach (string value in groups[key])
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
A:
the beginning is 1
the beginning is 2
B:
and the end is 1
and the end is 2
AB:
good morning to you 1
good morning to you 2
```

### OLD CODE

```
/// <summary>
/// Separates the List of string data into groups of data
/// </summary>
/// <param name="data">Array of string data</param>
/// <param name="groupNames">Array of group names</param>
/// <returns>Dictionary of List of string data broken into groups</returns>
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> SeparateGroups(string[] data, params string[] groupNames)
{
    return groupNames.ToDictionary(
        groupName => groupName, 
        groupName => data.Where(ag => ag.StartsWith(groupName) && ag.EndsWith(groupName)).ToList()
    );
}
```

Usage:

```
string[] groupNames = new[] { "A", "B", "AB" };
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filePath);
int count = lines.Length
Dictionary<string, List<string>> groups = SeparateGroups(lines, groupNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
List<string> groupA = lines.Where(s => s.StartsWith("A") && s.EndsWith("A")).ToList();
List<string> groupB = lines.Where(s => s.StartsWith("B") && s.EndsWith("B")).ToList();
```

Oh, and, I know that this is not your question, but... instead of

```
var count = File.ReadLines(path).Count();
```

... why not simply do this:

```
var count = lines.Length;
```

It avoids having to read the file twice.